# I was mistakenly versioning my root folder with Git. How do I delete and recover the space it is taking?

Tags: macos, mac, git

I don't know how it happened, but it seems I mistakenly initialized Git on my root folder on macOS a few months back, and it was versioning my whole root.

Now I barely have any space left in my drive (11gb of 250gb). How do I fix it to recover the drive space it is currently taking?

In 'about this mac' I can see that "system" is taking over 100gb of space, which is madness. I am very new to Git and versioning.

Comment: Open a Terminal, and type "cd /" and then "du -hs * .*" to see what is using the disk space in your root folder, including inside "hidden" folders like /.git.  I'm not sure that git is really the problem here...

Answer (score 1):

If you were versioning root without even knowing so, maybe you can just remove `/.git`.

1. Open Terminal.app.
2. `sudo rm -rf /.git/`.

Be sure **not to add any extra spaces there**. YOU COULD LOSE ALL OF YOUR DATA. If you are not sure of what you are doing, you can also try to find this and remove it by browsing the Finder. Then once you are ready to do so, empty Trash.

Comment: Even if the Op initialized the root folder as a Git repo, unless he/she also did "git add" and "git commit" on all the files, how would they automatically get added to git (and thus fill up the drive)?  I'm asking for 2 reasons: 1) I've never heard of automatically adding all files to git and tracking changes automatically, and 2) if that's not the real problem, what else could be going on to cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was wrong. It was true that I had accidentally initialized git on my root folder, and had been told that was probably the cause of all that wasted space and I believed it because I couldn't find the source, but upon trying your solutions and reading more and more realized that wasn't the cause of the issue. I read in a reddit thread about using DaisyDisk to be able to tell where the disk usage was off, and it helped me quickly find the sources of the wasted storage.

System cache. In `~/library/caches` I had over 30gb of cached info from adobe applications, spotify, etc.

Xcode had close to 20gb being used by devices. [Followed this advice](https://gist.github.com/ZevEisenberg/5a172662cb576872d1ab) and freed up 95% of all that space (and xcode and simulator still work fine).

The application also showed other places with high storage use and upon looking up what was safe to remove and what not, was able to finally recover over 75gb of space in the end.

I realize this makes the question irrelevant, so I would like to know what I should do about it (edit it?).

Thank you for your answers.